# Postgres COPY command gets Error: out of memory

Tags: postgresql

When copying a large amount of data (around 9GB) from CSV file into table, I get following error:

```
ERROR:  out of memory
 DETAIL:  Cannot enlarge string buffer containing 1073741632 bytes by 349 more bytes.
 CONTEXT:  COPY column_name line 13275136
```

A server (postgresql 10) has 8GB of memory and database has shared_buffers set to 2GB.

Can somebody suggest a solution, please. Or problem is instead in column_name length ( according to `CONTEXT:  COPY column_name line 13275136` message)

Answer (score 2):

> DETAIL:  Cannot enlarge string buffer containing 1073741632 bytes by
>   349 more bytes.
>   CONTEXT:  COPY column_name line 13275136

According to the error message, the offending row at this line number in the file is too large to be imported. `COPY` uses an internal buffer per row that can only grow to 1GB. It's impossible to import or export larger rows with COPY in existing versions of PostgreSQL (up to and including version 12)